# Circular duplicates should not prevent vote to delete

Tags: feature-request, bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, vote-to-delete

Some [!!FUN!!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29525972#29525972) happened with [a couple of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36019508), Q<sub>A</sub> had 3 close votes as duplicated against Q<sub>B</sub>, and Q<sub>B</sub> was hammered as duplicated of Q<sub>A</sub> (that's another bug). When both questions were finally closed, no one could vote to delete neither. This shouldn't happen.

I see two possible fixes, questions which duplicates are the same user shouldn't prevent delete voting, the system should try harder to prevent circular duplicates (in lieu of the dupehammers), or downvoted closed questions without positive scored answers shouldn't have restrictions about deleting. I'm not sure which would be ideal, and some of these solutions would affect more than this specific case (which may be beneficial).

Comment: Can you (normally) close question as duplicate of question which is itself a duplicate? Never tried that, but I think it should not be allowed.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Unfortunately, you can (for example, you could vote to close this question as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319614/redirection-to-https) (but don't, because it's not)).

Comment: I think that would just make the system a lot more complex, let's say that Question A is being closed as a duplicate of B (which at that moment was not a duplicate). Then afterwards B is closed as a duplicate of C, what should happen to A? Should they all be changed to be a duplicate of C?

Comment: @Cornstalks Why "Unfortunately"? Sometimes question A, while being a dupe of question B, has a useful answer on its own. If that answer also applies to question C, it could be closed as a dupe of A, but not B.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I personally think that one question should be considered the "canonical" one that all the duplicates get marked as a duplicate of. I agree that useful answers can be scattered amongst duplicates, in which case I think the correct solution is to either 1) merge the questions/answers, or 2) have the canonical question link to its various duplicates so users can more fully explore all the answers they may be interested in.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev those "not-quite-duplicates" are problem too: Question A has many useful answers, B is a dupe of A and contains additional useful answer, C is a dupe of A and have extra useful answer too. What to do with question D? Should you close as dupe of A, because it has most useful answers? B or C because those answers are applicable too?